# Dataset needed for CDR analysis

Tags: dataset

Can anyone please share some information on how to create data for CDR analysis?
or can please anyone share the existing data repository link.I need to do some analysis on call detail record using Hadoop.I tried different data generators but didn't get the desired result.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found a dataset from [Nodobo](http://nodobo.com/): http://nodobo.com/release.html

"The data includes 13035 call records, 83542 SMS records, and
5.2 million proximity records." -> [Paper](http://nodobo.com/papers/iet-el.pdf)

Comment: Links are expired. Please update the links

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a tool to generate CDR data. Please take look at link

> [Utitlity for CDR Data Generation](https://github.com/deshpandetanmay/cdr-data-generator)
>
> [Sample CDR Data](https://github.com/deshpandetanmay/cdr-data-generator#sample-data)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Call Detail Record (CDR) generator based on the CDR Tool, developed by Paul Kinlan:[CDR generator by Paul Kinlan](https://github.com/mayconbordin/cdr-gen)